# The Recyclerview is not showing the list

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and show the data into a recycler view. That API Contains an image URL and id. And I want to show the image from the URL and the id in the recycler view. But when I go to the Activity the recycler view is not showing the list. It is fetching the data from the API very well but it is not showing the data in the Recyclerview in a list format.

```
RecyclerviewAdapter.java

package com.madhulata.shriresume.shared;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.madhulata.shriresume.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

   private ArrayList<String> mImageNames;
   private ArrayList<String> mId;
   private Context mContext;



    public RecyclerviewAdapter(ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mId, Context mContext) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mId = mId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.resume_format,parent,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d("Recycler","on Bind Called");
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImageNames.get(position))
                .into(holder.resumeImage);

        holder.resumeId.setText(mId.get(position));

        holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView resumeImage;
        TextView  resumeId;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            resumeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.resumeLogo);
            resumeId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.resumeId);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.resumeTypeLayout);


        }
    }



}

***********************************SelectResume.java********************
package com.madhulata.shriresume.activity_dir;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.madhulata.shriresume.R;
import com.madhulata.shriresume.models.ResumeType;
import com.madhulata.shriresume.shared.RecyclerviewAdapter;
import com.madhulata.shriresume.shared.RetrofitClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class SelectResume extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView selectResumeList;
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> mId;
    private ArrayList<String> mUrls;
    ProgressBar p;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_resume);
        mId = new ArrayList<>();
        mUrls = new ArrayList<>();



        selectResumeList = findViewById(R.id.selectResumeList);



        getResume();

    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.i("Value","init Recycler View");
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(mUrls,mId,this);
        selectResumeList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectResumeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void getResume(){
        Log.i("Value","Call method");
        Call<List<ResumeType>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getResume();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResumeType>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Response<List<ResumeType>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    List<ResumeType> resume = response.body();

                    for (ResumeType r : resume){
                        mUrls.add(r.getUrl());
                        mId.add(r.getId());
                        Log.i("Value", mId.toString());
                    }
                }

                Log.i("Value","Call method 3");


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        initRecyclerView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is not showing?

**Your  `initRecyclerView();` called before you update your data from the services. Retrofit callback works in a separate thread.**

Try this instead of your method

```
private void getResume(){
        Log.i("Value","Call method");
        Call<List<ResumeType>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getResume();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResumeType>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Response<List<ResumeType>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    List<ResumeType> resume = response.body();

                    for (ResumeType r : resume){
                        mUrls.add(r.getUrl());
                        mId.add(r.getId());
                        Log.i("Value", mId.toString());
                    }
                initRecyclerView();
                }

                Log.i("Value","Call method 3");


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set adapter once at start in `onCreate()` even if your data is empty. You can add data later and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. The RecyclerView will be updated accordingly. This will save you from the overhead of setting adapter to RecyclerView each time you get some data.

```
public class SelectResume extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView selectResumeList;
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> mId;
    private ArrayList<String> mUrls;
    ProgressBar p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_resume);
        mId = new ArrayList<>();
        mUrls = new ArrayList<>();

        selectResumeList = findViewById(R.id.selectResumeList);

        initRecyclerView();
        getResume();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.i("Value","init Recycler View");
        RecyclerviewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(mUrls, mId, this);
        selectResumeList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectResumeList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void getResume(){
        Log.i("Value","Call method");
        Call<List<ResumeType>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getResume();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ResumeType>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Response<List<ResumeType>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    List<ResumeType> resume = response.body();
                    for (ResumeType r : resume){
                        mUrls.add(r.getUrl());
                        mId.add(r.getId());
                        Log.i("Value", mId.toString());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                Log.i("Value","Call method 3");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ResumeType>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectResume.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You receive the objects to show into RecyclerView from async network call. You need to update the adapter on the callback of your network call. Moreover I advice to initialize the adapter with empty list on the activity created, and after when you receive your data update the list with notifyDataSetChanged()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()